# Filtering table on the frontend - Vue.JS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, v-for

I have a table with students details, that I get from the db using v-for.
I'm trying to filter the table based on a field value. for starters, I have 3 inputs above the table, and every one of them is bound by v-model to update a corresponding key-value pair in an array of filters.
here is my code for the computed studentsList I loop through.

```
  computed:{
filteredStudentList:function(){
  console.log(this.lastNameSearch);
  let filteredStudents =[]

  let filtersArray = [
    ['lastName',this.lastNameSearch ],
    ['firstName',this.firstNameSearch],
    ['studentID',this.studentIDSearch ],  


    ///avoiding comparing to null or empty searchBox     
  ]
  let filteredFiltersArray = filtersArray.filter(pair=>{
    return pair[1] !=null       
  })
  let dFilteredFiltersArray = filteredFiltersArray.filter(pair=>{
    return pair[1] !=""       
  })
  console.log(filtersArray);
  console.log(dFilteredFiltersArray);


  // add students to the filtered array, if they are not there already and all the searchBoxes are empty
  this.studentsList.forEach(student=>{
    if (dFilteredFiltersArray.length==0 && filteredStudents.indexOf(student)==-1){
    filteredStudents.push(student)
    }else{
        dFilteredFiltersArray.forEach(([q,a])=>{
          Object.entries(student).forEach(([k,v])=>{
        if( k==q){
          if(!v.match(a)){              
              console.log(student);
              filteredStudents.filter(i=>{
              return i !=student
            })
          }                      
        }             
      })
    })
    }        
  })
  console.log(filteredStudents);
  return filteredStudents
}    
   },
```

Now, when I run it, whatever letter I type in a search box, it filters out all of the students.
Can anyone help me to figure out what is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0):

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    firstNameSearch: "",
    lastNameSearch: "",
    studentIDSearch: "",
    studentsList: [
      {
        firstName: "Dan",
        lastName:"Ramsey",
        studentID: "1",
      },
      {
        firstName: "Jenna",
        lastName:"Combs",
        studentID: "2",
      },
      {
        firstName: "Jill",
        lastName:"Barron",
        studentID: "3",
      },
    ],
  },
  computed: {
    filteredStudentList: function() { 
      let filteredStudents = this.studentsList;
      if (this.firstNameSearch && this.firstNameSearch.lenght != 0) {
        filteredStudents = filteredStudents.filter( student => {
          return student.firstName.search(this.firstNameSearch) != -1;
        })
      }

      if (this.lastNameSearch && this.lastNameSearch.lenght != 0) {
        filteredStudents = filteredStudents.filter( student => {
          return student.lastName.search(this.lastNameSearch) != -1;
        })
      }

      if (this.studentIDSearch && this.studentIDSearch.lenght != 0) {
        filteredStudents = filteredStudents.filter( student => {
          return student.studentID === this.studentIDSearch;
        })
      }
      return filteredStudents;
    }
  },
})
```

```css
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td, th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <table>
    <th>firstnamne</th>
    <th>lastname</th>
    <th>id</th>
    <tr v-for="student in filteredStudentList">
      <td>{{ student.firstName }}</td>
      <td>{{ student.lastName }}</td>
      <td>{{ student.studentID }}</td>
    </tr>
    <label for="firstNameSearch">First name</label>
    <input id="firstNameSearch" type="text" v-model="firstNameSearch"/>
    <label for="lastNameSearch">Last name</label>
    <input id="lastNameSearch" type="text" v-model="lastNameSearch"/>
    <label for="studentIDSearch">ID</label>
    <input id="studentIDSearch" type="text" v-model="studentIDSearch"/>
  </table>
</div>
```

I think this is an easier approach.
Edited with a snippet.

Comment: Still the same. No student in the table when I add text to any searchbox. Also, if I add text two or more search boxes, when I try to console.log the filtered list, I find that it contains duplicates